# Nav bar sobrepondo conteúdo da página!

Tags: html5, css3

Olá tenho uma pagina com um menu (nav bar) e quando clico em um link do menu a página deve direcionar a a *session* correspondente, por exemplo, quando clico no sobre possuo uma *session* sobre que deve ser exibida, acontece que quando faço isso a *session* está com uma parte escondida atras do menu, ou seja o `height` do menu não é respeitado como na imagem a seguir

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que está com um contorno azul é a session, percebam como ela vai até lá em cima atrás do menu.

HTML CSS

```css
nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;

}
nav a img{
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 0;

}

nav > a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: azure;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-family: serif
}

nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
}
nav ul li{
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px
}
nav ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: darkblue;

}
```

```html
 <nav>
    <a href="#top"><img src="imagens/Logo%20DMDUQUE%20Final.png"></a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#sobre">Sobre</a></li>
        <li><a href="#servicos">Serviços</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contato">Contato</a></li>                
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Marlyson, posta o HTML da nav bar.

Answer (score 3):

O que está acontecendo é que, como o seu elemento `<nav>` está com `position: fixed` ele não "ocupa espaço" na página, então o conteúdo debaixo começa no topo, em baixo da `<nav>`.

Coloca um `padding-top: 15px` (Sendo `15px` apenas um valor de exemplo, você pode mudar dependendo do código) no seu conteúdo que a barra superior vai deixar de sobrepor.

Comment: Vinicius, contece que quando a página é renderizada numa tela menor, como a de um celular por exemplo, o navBar é espremida e fica maior no sentido vertical, ocultando alguns itens da página, É possivel colocar o padding em termos do tamanho da nav bar: `padding-top: 100% da nav bar`?

Comment: @yoyo Eu acho que a melhor forma de fazer uma navbar que vai fixar na tela com scroll, sem a utilização de JS, seja com position: sticky.
Dá uma estudada que acredito que possa ser a solução que você esteja buscando: http://loopinfinito.com.br/2013/05/28/css-position-sticky/

Nesse caso, não aplique nenhum `padding-top`, e deixe o elemento `<nav>` com `position: sticky`

Answer (score -3):

O que também é possível nesse caso(não sei se é o certo, mas pra mim funcionou) é colocar um h1 ou div vazia antes do começo do HTML no conteúdo, com o ID do href e no CSS desse elemento: position: absolute, e um top com a posição em Px até onde deseja que a pagina desça.
exemplo:

```
<div id="seu-href" class="posição"></div>

.posição{
 position: absolute;
 top: 600px;  /*vai descer até o pixel 600*/}
```

Espero ter ajudado (:

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).